# Populate Excel using an API

Tags: excel, vba, api, powerquery

I want to look at the card prices of my yu-gi-oh cards where I would get real-time data when I refresh.
I have been using the public API for the price data: https://yugiohprices.docs.apiary.io/#

I manually entered the name, rarity, and print tag for each card. I was hoping to use this API to populate price data into my worksheet.

My thinking is I need the API to call each print_tag and return the request onto the three price columns.
Would I need to create a for loop in VBA to do that or is there an easier method using PowerQuery?

VBA code I have so far:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub restAPICall()
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String
Dim json As Object

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strUrl = "http://yugiohprices.com/api/price_for_print_tag/print_tag"
blnAsync = True

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Conset-Type", "application/json"
    .Send
    
    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    strResponse = .ResponseText
    
End With
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You already successfully queried the data from the remote API!

Basically the steps you'd need to do:

1. Loop through all the links in your `link` column and for each
2. Fetch Data (done)
3. As the API returns the data in JSON you need to convert the JSON-string. A well known library which can help you with this is available on GitHub [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) (converts it to a Dictionary)
4. Extract the wanted field(s) (probably `price_data`) and get the values
5. Write the price in the corresponding cell on the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub restAPICall()
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String, Prices As String
Dim High As String, Low As String, Avg As String
Dim strUrl As String, Print_Tag As String
Dim PriceArray() As String
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strUrl = "http://yugiohprices.com/api/price_for_print_tag/"
blnAsync = True

'Get last row of column C (print tag)
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To LastRow
'Get print tag
Print_Tag = Trim(Range("C" & i).Value)
'Clear values
strResponse = ""
High = ""
Low = ""
Avg = ""

'Make request with print_tag
With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl & Print_Tag, blnAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Conset-Type", "application/json"
    .Send

    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    strResponse = .ResponseText

End With

'Get prices
strResponse = Replace(strResponse, ",", "")
strResponse = Replace(strResponse, Chr(34) & "high" & Chr(34) & ":", "|")
strResponse = Replace(strResponse, Chr(34) & "low" & Chr(34) & ":", "|")
strResponse = Replace(strResponse, Chr(34) & "average" & Chr(34) & ":", "|")
strResponse = Replace(strResponse, Chr(34) & "shift" & Chr(34) & ":", "|")

PriceArray = Split(strResponse, "|")
High = PriceArray(1)
Low = PriceArray(2)
Avg = PriceArray(3)

'Put prices in column
Range("F" & i).Value = Low
Range("G" & i).Value = Avg
Range("H" & i).Value = High

Next
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objRequest = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code worked for me.  Full credit goes to **u/NegativeSpeech** on reddit for sharing his work.

Comment: Also, you don't switch screen-updating back on at end.